# Two Tables with same class name, but changes to the Class applied to one table only

Tags: html, css

In my ascx UI page am having Two html dynamic tables with same class name "transfer_options", requirement is to delete some content from both the tables using the same class name.

I tried `$('.transfer_options td:last img').remove();`but its removing img from first table only.

second table image is still there. how can i delete the last td image of both the tables with class name only.

```html
<table id="layout_PCDZADE_ctl00" class="transfer_options" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZADE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_01</a>
        <img src="~/test.gif" id="ctl00_Download" alt=">" class="download_bullet">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZDSE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_02</a>
        <img src="~/test.gif" id="ctl00_Downloads" alt=">" class="download_bullet">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="layout_PCDAGJNE_ctl00" class="transfer_options" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZADAQE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_01.01</a>
        <img src="~/test.gif" id="ctl00_Download" alt=">" class="download">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZDSFVE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_01.02</a>
        <img src="~/test.gif" id="ctl00_Downloads" alt=">" class="download">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain your `td:last` into a separate find so it finds last td in each table otherwise the selector will just find the last td in all tables:

```js
$('.transfer_options').find('td:last img').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="layout_PCDZADE_ctl00" class="transfer_options" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZADE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_01</a>
        <img src="~/test.gif" id="ctl00_Download" alt=">" class="download_bullet">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZDSE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_02</a>
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" id="ctl00_Downloads" alt=">" class="download_bullet">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="layout_PCDAGJNE_ctl00" class="transfer_options" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZADAQE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_01.01</a>
        <img src="~/test.gif" id="ctl00_Download" alt=">" class="download">
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="layout_PCDZDSFVE_ctl00_Download" class="download_link" href="">Task_01.02</a>
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300" id="ctl00_Downloads" alt=">" class="download">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.transfer_options td:last img')` returns an Array of HTMLElements. To remove each you have to call `.remove()` for each of them.
With jQuery you can do this like that:

```
$('.transfer_options td:last img').each((index, element) => {
   element.remove();
});
```

Comment: This is wrong - you can call `.remove` on the array and it will remove all elements in the array, you don't need to iterate through each and call remove separately.  The problem is the selector is only returning the the last td in all tables, not in each table

Comment: Ok this was my fault now I see the Problem. But your answer seems to solve it